# How to use objectPoints parameter in stereoCalibrate() method, opencv 3.0

Tags: opencv

I cannot seem to determine where to find this input array for stereoCalibrate() method. The opencv documentation describes it as "vector of vectors of the calibration pattern points" which seems like it must come from an object detection calibration. Yet I have went through the opencv source code calibration for my cameras, and the xml file the calibration info was saved to has everything but objectPoints. Where/how do I determine this parameter?

Here's a link to the documentation:   http://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d0c/group__calib3d.html#ga246253dcc6de2e0376c599e7d692303a

Thanks,
Rowan

Answer (score 1):

From the [stereo calibration example](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/stereo_calib.cpp):

```
for( i = 0; i < nimages; i++ )
{
    for( j = 0; j < boardSize.height; j++ )
    {
        for( k = 0; k < boardSize.width; k++ )
        {
            objectPoints[i].push_back(Point3f(k*squareSize, j*squareSize, 0));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

object points are detected points from camera frames, usually chessboard, circle grid.

generally, you should print out the chessboard(or other pattern), open your camera, and grab frames of the chessboard with different rotation and distance. easy detect algorithm would find the chessboard corners, object points. filling these points of into the calibration function. you would get camera intrinsic and extrinsic matrix and save them in a xml/yml file.

no object points would be place in the xml/yml file.

Comment: Are you sure? "detected points from camera frames" sounds a lot like image points, to me. Object points should be real 3D points in the world frame, right?